# GROUP BY with date range

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have a table with 4 columns, `id`, `Stream` which is text, `Duration` (int), and `Timestamp` (datetime).  There is a row inserted for every time someone plays a specific audio stream on my website.  `Stream` is the name, and `Duration` is the time in seconds that they are listening.  I am currently using the following query to figure up total listen hours for each week in a year:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(`Timestamp`), (SUM(`Duration`)/60/60) FROM logs_main
WHERE `Stream`="asdf" GROUP BY YEARWEEK(`Timestamp`);
```

This does what I expect... presenting a total of listen time for each week in the year that there is data.

However, I would like to build a query where I have a result row for weeks that there may not be any data.  For example, if the 26th week of 2006 has no rows that fall within that week, then I would like the `SUM` result to be 0.

Is it possible to do this?  Maybe via a JOIN over a date range somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tried an true old school solution is to set up another table with a bunch of date ranges that you can outer join with for the grouping (as in the other table would have all of the weeks in it with a begin / end date).

In this case, you could just get by with a table full of the values from YEARWEEK:

```
201100
201101
201102
201103
201104
```

And here is a sketch of a sql statement:

```
SELECT year_weeks.yearweek , (SUM(`Duration`)/60/60) 

FROM year_weeks LEFT OUTER JOIN logs_main
   ON year_weeks.yearweek = logs_main.YEARWEEK(`Timestamp`)

WHERE `Stream`="asdf" GROUP BY year_weeks.yearweek;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up finding an alternate solution (completely different than what I asked, otherwise I would post here), but I will simply use this method in the future.  It's too bad there isn't a way to generate that dataset of YEARWEEK in the query directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion.  might not be exactly what you are looking for.

But say you had a simple table with one column `[year_week]` that contained the values of 1, 2, 3, 4... 52

You could then theoretically:

```
SELECT

A.year_week, 
(SELECT SUM('Duration')/60/00) FROM logs_main WHERE
 stream = 'asdf' AND YEARWEEK('TimeStamp') = A.year_week GROUP BY YEARWEEK('TimeStamp')) 

FROM

tblYearWeeks A
```

this obviously needs some tweaking... i've done several similar queries in other projects and this works well enough depending on the situation.

If your looking for a one table/sql based solution then that is deffinately something I would be interested in as well!

Comment: I might be missing something, but I'm not seeing where you're actually joining to tblYearWeeks...

Comment: its not a join. its a sub query of tblyearweeks which guarantees that all records from the tblyearweeks is returned, and then the sum of the duration is returned by the sub query.